# Is it safe to share Smart Contract code from GitHub with developer?

Tags: security, ico

Hi

We have finished our smart contract development and are looking at candidates for a security audit

Is it safe to share our GitHub repo with a smart contract developer in order for him to give pricing and timeframe for a security audit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it shouldn't be a problem and it's pretty common in the Ethereum space to openly share the code.

As a matter of fact you will have to make the code available and verify it on Etherscan if you want people to trust that the contract does what you claim it does.

And even if you don't share the code for the contract, once deployed if someone really wanted to get it they could get it from the compiled code.